# Best way to debug MySQL connections that are being closed on me after ~39 minutes?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring, c3p0

I have hibernate 3.3, c3p0, MySql 5.1, and Spring.
The MySQL connections in my service calls are consistently being closed after ~39 minutes.  The natural running time of my service call is on the order of ~5 hours.

I've tried changing various c3p0 config, etc, to avoid the 39 minute cap.  No luck.

Is there a more direct, systematic way to log or troubleshoot this?  i.e. can I find out *why* the connection is being closed, and by *whom*, at which layer?

Update:  stack trace

```
24 Oct 2010 02:22:12,262 [WARN] 012e323c-df4b-11df-89ed-97e9a9c1ac19 (Foobar Endpoint : 3) org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08003
24 Oct 2010 02:22:12,264 [ERROR] 012e323c-df4b-11df-89ed-97e9a9c1ac19 (Foobar Endpoint : 3) org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter: No operations allowed after connection closed.
24 Oct 2010 02:22:12,266 [ERROR] 012e323c-df4b-11df-89ed-97e9a9c1ac19 (Foobar Endpoint : 3) org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener: Could not synchronize database state with session
```

Comment: Look at this: http://www.databasesandlife.com/automatic-reconnect-from-hibernate-to-mysql/

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace? If yes, add it to the question.

Comment: Is there a firewall between the client and mysql server? Or on either machine?

Comment: Change maxPoolSize. If the connection dies at a significantly different time, you be suffering from a connection leak (can't get more connections).

Comment: no firewall;  client and server are on the same machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have hibernate 3.3, c3p0, MySql 5.1, and Spring. The MySQL connections in my service calls are consistently being closed after ~39 minutes. The natural running time of my service call is on the order of ~5 hours.

I'm not sure I understood. Do you have processes that are supposed to run for 5 hours but currently get aborted after ~39mn (or probably 2400 seconds). Can you confirm? What is previously working? Did you change anything?

Meanwhile, here are some ideas:

- start with the database (see [B.5.2.11. Communication Errors and Aborted Connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/communication-errors.html))

  - start the server with the [`--log-warnings`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings) option and check the logs for suspicious messages
  - see if you can reproduce the problem using a MySQL client from the db host
  - if it works, do the same thing from the app server machine
  - it if works, you'll know MySQL is ok
- move at the app server level

  - activate logging (of Hibernate and [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#configuring_logging)) to get a **full stack trace** and/or more hints about the culprit
  - also please show your C3P0 configuration settings

And don't forget that C3P0's configuration when using Hibernate is [very specific](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#hibernate-specific) and some settings must go in a `c3p0.properties` file.

Comment: My process is batch processing for a large workload.  I've artificially limited the workload -- it completes within 10 minutes.  When I increase the workload size, closed connections result around ~34 to ~39 minutes.

Comment: MySQL query log confirms that the connection is being ended by the client, not MySQL itself.  The client initiates a rollback, then opens up a new (different) connection.

Comment: @Aaron Ok, that's a first interesting step in the diagnostic. Do you get any useful stacktrace (a full stacktrace) on the client side? Why does it rollback the transaction?

Comment: It was the connection pooling itself, and not MySQL, that was closing the connection and thus rolling it back.  I have working c3p0 config now that doesn't close the connection, although I can't fully explain why.  Still investigating.

Answer (score 0):

Auto reconnect configuration

http://hibernatedb.blogspot.com/2009/05/automatic-reconnect-from-hibernate-to.html

Comment: Hmm... what do you mean exactly? This link doesn't explain why the connection gets closed after 39mn (and configuring a connection pool to renew connections won't help). Did I miss something?